# Retrieve CPrintInfo

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

Is there a way to retrieve CPrintInfo, *not only when application do print or print preview* (for instance, when I click on some dummy button or something) ? If yes, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Can you be more specific at what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure. I have an SDI app, with a spitt window. In the left pane I have an CTreeView, and in the right pane I have an CScrollView. (it is a kind of explorer application). In CTreeView (left pane) I have just two items. When I select the first one, I have in CScrollView something dummy drawn ... but when I select the second item from CTreeView (from left pane) I want draw in CScrollView (right pane) the print preview result of CScrollView, but inside into CScrollView, without MFC print preview frame !!! ... this is the task ... and I think I can, if I can get CPrintInfo ...

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to render an image to the view of what would get printed.  I'm not sure why you need CPrintInfo to accomplish that.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to draw into CScrollView the printing result just like look into print preview frame, with a gray background, with white paper, and inside of this paper I would like to draw the image ... but I don't know how may paper I have, the pages rectangle, etc., these information I could find into CPrintInfo ...

Comment: Sorry, I should leave the office now, I will come back tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Maybe with a lot of plumbing you can reuse the MFC print preview stuff, but honestly it's easier to drop down to GDI level printing and do your own print preview. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . You need to calculate your own amount of pages etc yourself anyway depending on the printer your print preview should 'emulate'.

Comment: How about WTL? Not quiet as low-level and perhaps more along the lines of what an MFC programmer can understand.

Comment: True, and it includes some basic functionality to draw the page of a print preview window, too. So worth a look for the OP.